# Bash command to search for a string in file and replace the value with value from another file

Tags: bash, replace

I have two files file a.) xmlFile.xml b.) emails.txt

xmlFile.xml has the following structure repeated multiple times

```
<gname>Office</gname>
<uname>person</uname>
```

emails.txt has list of email addresses

```
email1@company.com
email2@company.com
...
```

What I want to accomplish is to replace "person" in xmlFile.xml with subsequent value taken from emails.txt

I have tried

```
# while read email ; do sed  "s/person/$email/g" xmlFile.xml > xmlFile.new; done < emails.txt
```

However I endup with file that has all "person" values replaced with the last email from emails.txt

Thanks,
Filip

Comment: You need to have sed only replace the first occurrence, then repeat once for each line. This will be slow, of course. The sane answer is, I believe, *use Perl*. :-P Alternatively, you could transform your emails.txt into a giant sed script and run it once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{e[i++]=$0;next} /person/{sub("person",e[j++])}1' emails.txt xmlFile.xml
```

#### Explanation

1. `NR==FNR`: This is only true when `awk` is reading the first file. It essentially tests total number of records seen (NR) vs the input record in the current file (FNR).
2. `e[i++]=$0`: Create an array named **e** who's index increments by 1 (`i++`)and who's value is equal to the current record `$0`. This array will hold our emails
3. `next`: Ignore the rest of the script if this is reached, start over with a new input record
4. `/person/`: Only perform the subsequent code if the current record matches the regex "person"
5. `sub("person",e[j++])`: Substitute the literal value "person" for a value in our array **e** that we created earlier.  Increment this array `j++` for the next record we match
6. **1**: Always returns true, essentially a shortcut for `{print $0}`, or output our current record

#### Proof Of Concept

```
$ cat emails.txt
email1@company.com
email2@company.com
email3@company.com
email4@company.com
email5@company.com
email6@company.com
email7@company.com
email8@company.com
email9@company.com

$ cat xmlFile.xml
<gname>Office</gname>
<uname>person</uname>
<gname>Office</gname>
<uname>person</uname>
<gname>Office</gname>
<uname>person</uname>
<gname>Office</gname>
<uname>person</uname>
<gname>Office</gname>
<uname>person</uname>
<gname>Office</gname>
<uname>person</uname>
<gname>Office</gname>
<uname>person</uname>
<gname>Office</gname>
<uname>person</uname>
<gname>Office</gname>
<uname>person</uname>

$ awk 'NR==FNR{e[i++]=$0;next} /person/{sub("person",e[j++])}1' emails.txt xmlFile.xml
<gname>Office</gname>
<uname>email1@company.com</uname>
<gname>Office</gname>
<uname>email2@company.com</uname>
<gname>Office</gname>
<uname>email3@company.com</uname>
<gname>Office</gname>
<uname>email4@company.com</uname>
<gname>Office</gname>
<uname>email5@company.com</uname>
<gname>Office</gname>
<uname>email6@company.com</uname>
<gname>Office</gname>
<uname>email7@company.com</uname>
<gname>Office</gname>
<uname>email8@company.com</uname>
<gname>Office</gname>
<uname>email9@company.com</uname>
```

The above script assumes that `person` is a literal value. If it is not, then..

Replace: `/person/{sub("person",emails[j++])}`
With: `/<uname>/{sub(".*","<uname>"emails[j++]"</uname>")}`

Comment: The solution seems perfect, but to be a good answer some explanation for *awk* novices should be given.

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this would be to use in-place editing:

```
while read email ; do sed -i "s/person/$email/;q" xmlFile.xml; done < emails.txt
```

If there's little or nothing more to the XML file than what you've show, just reconstruct it:

```
sed -e 'i <gname>Office</gname>' -e 's|.*|<uname>&</uname>|' emails.txt > newxmlFile.xml
```

without even touching the  existing `xmlFile.xml`.

However, you should probably use an XML parser such as [`xmlstarlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thanks Dennis, The first example resulted each "person" being changed to the first email in the emails.txt, however the second example did work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it using bash & xmlstarlet!

```
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d "" -a array < emails.txt                   # read file with email addresses into array
n=$(xmlstarlet sel -T -t -v "count(//uname)" -n xmlFile.xml)    # count "uname" nodes in XML file
xmlFileStr="$(< xmlFile.xml)"                                   # read XML file into variable


if [[ $n -eq ${#array[@]} ]]; then   # if the number of nodes & email addresses is equal ...
   for ((i=1; i <= ${n}; i+=1)); do
      xmlFileStr="$(printf '%s' "$xmlFileStr" | xmlstarlet ed -P -t -u "//uname[${i}]" -v "${array[$((i-1))]}")"
   done
fi

printf '%s\n' "$xmlFileStr" > xmlFile.xml
cat xmlFile.xml
```